# Scala Regex Pattern Match not able to get it to work

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying to write a regex for having string separated by dots. For example,

```
"abc", "abc.def", "a.b.c.e.f"
```

are all valid, but

```
"abc..def", ".abc", "abc."
```

are not valid

Here is my regex code in scala

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val TestPattern = "^([a-z]+)(\\.?[a-z]+)*".r
    val x: String = "abc.def.hij"

    x match {
      case TestPattern(a,b) => println(a + b)
      case _ => println("Not Found")
    }
  }
}
```

So here is my regex,

```
"^([a-z]+)(\\.?[a-z]+)*".r
```

which has two components,

```
1. Starts with a-z
2. Repeat (has 0 or 1 dot, one or more from a-z) zero or more times
```

But,

```
Input: abc.def.hij
Output: abc.hij
```

I don't understand why

```
.def
```

doesn't show up in my output.

Answer (score 2):

With the repeated group, you only get the last match.

To get them all, use `findFirstMatchIn` or similar.

There are certainly duplicate questions.

```
scala> val r0 = "([a-z]+)".r.unanchored
r0: scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex = ([a-z]+)

scala> val m0 = r0 findFirstMatchIn x
m0: Option[scala.util.matching.Regex.Match] = Some(abc)

scala> val r1 = "(\\.?[a-z]+)".r.unanchored
r1: scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex = (\.?[a-z]+)

scala> val m1 = r1 findFirstMatchIn m0.get.after
m1: Option[scala.util.matching.Regex.Match] = Some(.def)

scala> r1 findFirstMatchIn m1.get.after
res2: Option[scala.util.matching.Regex.Match] = Some(.hij)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like shown in the other answers, you will always get the last match of a group that was matched multiple times. This is a limitation of the underlying Java regular expression engine.

In your case it might be better to split the value first and the evaluate the individual groups:

```
    scala> val nameSeparator="""\.""".r
    nameSeparator: scala.util.matching.Regex = \.

    scala> val namePart="""[a-z]+""".r
    namePart: scala.util.matching.Regex = [a-z]+


    scala> val parts=nameSeparator.split("abc.def.ghi")
    parts: Array[String] = Array(abc, def, ghi)

    scala> parts.forall(!namePart.unapplySeq(_).isEmpty)
    res20: Boolean = true
```

The last expression checks, whether all elements in the array parts match to the regular expression namePart.

If you have a more complex problem (e.g. expression starts with a prefix, then there are multiple groups with different separators and then a suffix follows) it might be better to switch directly to parser combinators:

```
    scala> :paste
    // Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)
    import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

    object NameParser extends RegexParsers {
      def separator : Parser[String] = """\.""".r
      def namePart : Parser[String] = """[a-z]+""".r
      def name : Parser[List[String]] = repsep(namePart, separator)

      def apply(input: String) = parseAll(name, input)
    }

    // Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

    import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers
    defined module NameParser

    scala> NameParser("abc.def.ghi")
    res24: NameParser.ParseResult[List[String]] = [1.12] parsed: List(abc, def, ghi)
```

The example can be easily adapted to a more complex parser. And if you need some error handling, parser combinators can be easier extended for that than a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture complete group as well as the last group:

```
    object Test {
      def main(args: Array[String]) {

          val TestPattern = """^([a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)*)""".r
          val x = "abc.def.hij"

          x match {
            case TestPattern(a, b) => println(a)
            case _ => println("Not Found")
          }
      }
    }
```

> EDIT:
>
> 1. In triple quoted string there is no need for escape character, hence
>      a single backslash works.
> 2. "case TestPattern(a)" does not work because number of parameters has to be same as number of capture-groups.
>      Each open-paranthesis starts a new capture-group.
>      For instance """^([a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)*)""".r has 2 capture-groups,
>      """^(([a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)*))""".r has 3.
>      So the later will match with TestPattern(a, b, c).
> 3. Since in this case the second capture-group is not needed, we can use a non-capture-group, which starts with (?: instead of (.
>      When regex is changed to """^([a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+)*)""".r, TestPattern(a) => println(a) works.

Comment: What is the difference between a single backslash and a double? Also why does "case TestPattern(a) => println(a), does not work? Isn't the whole pattern has only one component?